# How to do facebook login without opening a browser at all?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

The IOS app I'm currently working on uses FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions, which opens a browser in the app for user to login to facebook. Then, the browser closes, and the app uses the FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult to proceed.

However, I want to change it so that the app uses preset settings to log into facebook in the background, without actually opening a browser at all. To put it in a simpler way, the app should not open the browser, but still cause a regular log-in. Is that possible?

Just to clarify, this feature is only intended when the app is running in the developer mode, not for the users.

Thank you!

EDIT: I also found FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount, which

> Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through
>      the device Settings.

However, I have no idea about how to implement this in swift, and I cannot find any resource online besides the brief description in FacebookSDK's documentation. It will be great if someone can help!